# Install Kali Linux on RAID0 (as dual boot Windows 7 & Kali)

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, raid, boot-loader, kali-linux

I’m currently trying to install Kali Linux on my laptop [as described here](http://em3rgency.com/dual-boot-kali-windows-7/).
The problem is I’ve a laptop (MSI GT70) with a Raid 0 (2x 500Gb) and Windows 7 installed on it.

At the point where I’ve to select the device for the boot loader installation, selecting `/dev/sda5` (as described in the tutorial) won’t work.

While searching for a solution I’ve found [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43036/how-do-i-install-grub-on-a-raid-system-installation) which says that I’ve to enter the name of the raid array.
I’ve tried to find the name of my raid using the command `ls –l /dev/mapper`, which doesn’t work: it only prints one entry to the console (`crw-rw-rw  1 root ……. control`).

How can I find the correct device for the boot loader?

(Btw. I come from the windows world and I’ve almost no Linux experience…)

Answer (score 1):

The issue with following a tutorial is that not everyone has the same number of devices or may not be configured identically.  If you're trying to setup a dual boot with Win7/8 you will select the Kali installation device with the UEFI/EFI designation.  You will have to go through the manual setup so that you can select the non-partitioned space (that you should have configured before starting) for Kali to install to.  Since you're new to Linux you might want to work with all files in the same partition (you will see a designation as recommended for new users).  After the installation, you will need to enter Kali's CLI and update Grub (the Linux boot loader) so that you can see both Win7/8 and Kali.

Here's a nice tutorial for you: http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/01/14/how-to-dual-boot-kali-linux-1-0-9-and-windows-78-on-a-pc-with-uefi-firmware/